# Create (export) well styled word document using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, ms-word

I'm looking for a method to create well styled word document using ReactJs.

More information.

I've designed a layout in the exact same size of an A4 sheet. There are input boxes that users can input the information to that layout. after entering all the required information. I need to provide a method to export the current layout in to a Ms Word (.doc or .docx) document.
I've attached an image (taken from the internet) to show what kind of layout that I'm creating in React. I need the same to be in the word document with exactly the same styles.

[Example Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXd8J.jpg)

Hoping a solution, thank you.